# Strange Behavior of IDictionary and Dictionary

Tags: generics, c#-4.0

I have following classes

```
public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shop
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Xyz
    {
        public string Abc { get; set; }
    }
```

Why is that following is not allowed

```
IDictionary<Person, IDictionary<Shop, Xyz>> blahItem
           = new Dictionary<Person, Dictionary<Shop, Xyz>>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason that you can't do:

```
IDictionary<string, Control> dict = new Dictionary<string, Button>();
```

Suppose that were allowed... we could have:

```
Dictionary buttonDict = new Dictionary<string, Button>();
IDictionary<string, Control> controlDict = buttonDict;

controlDict["bang"] = new TextArea();
Button error = buttonDict["bang"];
```

Basically you'd violate type safety - `IDictionary` isn't *covariant* in either its key or value types.

Search for "generic variance" and "covariance" to find more details, including the limited support (e.g. for `IEnumerable<T>` which *can* be used safely in a covariant way) in C# 4.

Comment: oh, So you mean the value type i.e.  IDictionary<Shop, Xyz> is causing the covariance issue, Ok, now I got it, thanks a ton Jon..